# ASP.NET, login control, authentication, https/ssl, cookie path

Tags: asp.net, ssl, forms-authentication

I have a login control which authenticates (form authentication), but not using https/ssl.  I figured out that it was the cookie path.  I know it's case sensitive, so I set it to /newYork, which is exactly the way the directory name is cased (OS is Vista), but the authentication didn't work under https.  I set it to /newyork and the authentication worked under https.  I'm just wondering why this worked.  In https, does the set cookie work differently?

Answer (score 2):

The cookie path is case-sensitive:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313116

it is also normalized to lower case.